# Possibility of Create Site Specific CSS in a Multisite

Tags: multisite

I would like to know that using multisite feature, is it possible to have exactly same multiple wordpress sites, same content, same themes, (each on its own subdomain) but having few css styles specific to each site?

If so, then how can we achieve this.

Comment: You could use child themes!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can add website specific class to BODY, for example.

Best approach is to create little multisite enabled plugin, that adds some class to BODY in `body_class` filter.

```
function customBodyClass( $classes ) {
  global $current_blog;
  $classes[] = 'website-'.$current_blog->blog_id;
  return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'body_class', 'customBodyClass' );
```

All themes has to use `body_class()` function in BODY tag, obviously.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I really appreciate your effort. If it is possible for you to also illustrate, how can we make site specific options then I shall be immensely thankful to you. Options that are unique to a site.

Comment: If my post answered your question, then you can "accept" it. Site specific options ... well, if you _transform_ [this tutorial](https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Options_Pages) to stand-alone plugin, and activate it in multi-site, then every site's admin will have its custom options page, and its settings will be site-specific (when called by `get_option(...)` function).

Comment: Thank you very much for your efforts Marek, and sorry for accepting it late. I was like stuck in projects, didn't get time to get back to wp.